# jdbc oracle driver error 17024 no data read

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to run an insert to an Oracle database with an SQL statement that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO browsers (browsers.id,browsers.browser,browsers.engine,browsers.platform,browsers.version,browsers.grade) VALUES (BROWSERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?)
```

However, the jdbc driver keeps returning the error message:

SQL Problem: No data read
SQL State: 02000
Vendor Error: 17024
java.sql.SQLException: No data read

The execution of the statement proceeds as expected.  However, since this is an insert, I'm trying to also obtain the id of the new record.

See below in my Java code where I'm getting the error message:

```
   try{
      connection = getConnection();

      if(connectionException == false)
      {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = query.getPreparedStatement(connection);         
        statement.executeUpdate(); //<<< This executes fine.
        if(query.getQueryType() == Query.Type.INSERT)
        {
            //Get the id assigned to the new record
            //If we are dealing with a Link Table then we don't need to retrieve any generated ids.
            if(query.isLinkTable() == false)
            {
              resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
              if(!resultSet.wasNull())//<<< This is where I'm getting the error.                  
              {
                if(resultSet.next())
                {
                  query.setNewRecordID(resultSet.getInt(1));
                  //System.out.println(query.getNewRecordID());                       
                }
                else
                {
                  if(Editor.isLoggingEnabled())           
                  {                      
                    throw new SQLException("Database.executeInsertUpdate - on INSERT - Unable to retrieve id value");
                  }
                }
             }
             resultSet.close();
             resultSet = null;                 
           }
        }
        connection.commit();
        statement.close();
        statement = null;               
      }
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
17:48:56,219 ERROR Database:882 - Database.executeInsertUpdate - query: INSERT I
NTO browsers (browsers.id,browsers.browser,browsers.engine,browsers.platform,bro
wsers.version,browsers.grade) VALUES (BROWSERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?)
SQL Problem: No data read
SQL State: 02000
Vendor Error: 17024
java.sql.SQLException: No data read
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.wasNullValue(OracleStatement.java:
4099)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.wasNull(Insensitive
ScrollableResultSet.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.wasNull(DelegatingRes
ultSet.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.wasNull(DelegatingRes
ultSet.java:210)
        at com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Database.executeInsertUpdate(Database.java
:841)
        at com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Editor.insert(Editor.java:1922)
        at com.tacticalenterprisesltd.Editor.Process(Editor.java:800)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.browsers_jsp._jspService(browsers_jsp.java:178)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

Comment: If the query is working in SQL developer, then it should work with JDBC as well. I think the problem is not the insert statement but the remaining code. Please post the full code where you are setting the parameters and issuing the statement.

Comment: Show us your Java code that runs this statement

Comment: I've updated my post with the java code that executes my insert statement.  According to my stacktrace the line indicated in the code is what's causing the error.

Comment: So, what does `getPreparedStatement(connection);` do? Where are you passing the actual SQL `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I have a Query object that retrieves the sql statement, and sets the parameters. Hence the line: query.getPreparedStatement(connection).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from the code snippet how the `PreparedStatement` is getting created. I think it is hidden in the `getPreparedStatement(con)` method.

One thing you may want to check is, are you specifying in the `preparedstatement` creation that it should return generated keys. For ex: `con.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`? If not, please add and test.

Comment: Furthermore, Oracle's behavior when using the `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` flag may be to return the `ROWID` value rather than the autogenerated primary key.  Passing an array containing the column name(s) should work better.  Check out documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#i1056887

Comment: When the Query object retrieves the sql statement, in the case of dealing with Oracle, I do use the following: PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(toString(), getFieldsAsStringArray());  The toString() method returns the insert statement and the getFieldsAsStringArray() method returns a String[] array of all the field names.  I was just reading another post elsewhere and they indicate not loading all the field names but just the primary key field name in the String[] array.  I was thinking of giving that a try.

Comment: I also noticed I'm using an older jdbc driver and have just downloaded the latest ojdbc7.jar.  I'm going to test again and let you know what happens.

Comment: OK...I'm back.  I updated my code and installed a new ojdbc7.jar driver.  Still I'm having the same problem.  I've added my full stacktrace to this post.  Hopefully, someone can see where the problem lies?

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM!  It was that method call wasNull().  I was using it inappropriately.  The condition should really be: if(resultSet == null).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `preparedStmt.getResultSet()` instead of `preparedStmt.executeQuery()` Insert doesn't return any result data back. If this is not the case, we need to see more of your code.